# Django REST framework: Serializer to use max_length from model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a model

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254)
```

and related serializer

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=254)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name',)
```

Is there a way to make `CharField` automatically detect `max_length` from the model and use that in validation?

Using `Person._meta.get_field('name').max_length` could be an option but feels a bit cumbersome to be used in every field. Maybe overriding `CharField` with custom implementation? Or is there other options?

Comment: Use a `ModelSerializer`, and let Django convert the fields to their serializer field counterparts.

Comment: This seems to work fine when fields are just declared in Meta section. But if there is a need to add custom arguments to fields, then e.g. max_length is not transferred from model. For example `name = serializers.CharField(required=True)` doesn't use max_length validation

Comment: You can use `extra_kwargs` to inject extra parameters: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to translate a model in a straightforward way to a serializer, you can use a `ModelSerializer`. You can inject extra parameters to the constructors of the serializer fields with the [**`extra_kwargs`** field <sup>[drf-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments), so:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name',)
        extra_kwargs = {
            'name': {'required': True}
        }
```